# A sample of read()

Tags: java

I wrote a simple program:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Integer first = in.read();
System.out.println(first);
```

But for example when I input 13, print 49!!!Why?

Comment: try Integer first = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read()` method reads first `char` from input, in your case of `13` it is `'1'` and  `49` is the `int` value of `char` `'1'` you need to use

```
Integer first = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
```

**note**: + handle input validation

Comment: Tnx, But basically for example in codeforces I want input a series of numbers (very huge) that separating whit single space. If use Scanner class, I got TIMELIMIT so I must use BufferedReader class. I know we can use readLine then use split method, But I want more performance!Is there exist any other way?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `in.read()` it will return int value of element. Then you insert 13 it will reads a single character. So `49` is int value of char `1`

You should use following

```
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  Integer first = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine());
  System.out.println(first);
```

Read [more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

`read()` methods returns the int value of the single character that it reads

> public int read()
>            throws IOException Reads a single character. Overrides: read in class Reader Returns: **The character read, as an integer in the
>   range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has
>   been reached**

Therefore if you wanna read the whole line try

```
Integer first = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
```